# Chrome does not update the head tag when going to the next page in the same domain

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, caching

I am running into an issue in Chrome on a webpage that I building.

When I link from a page p1 -> p2, on certain links, chrome does not update the `<head>` tag including meta information, canonical tags etc. So p2 has the information of p1 in its `<head>`. Is that a common behavior which is happens on Chrome during caching.

No issues in any other browser.

Comment: Can you tell us more about which framework and technologies are you using? your tag suggests angular, but are you using something like helmet or server side rendering?

Comment: I am using angular as the framework, Contentful as CMS, Webpack to create the distribution folder and the pages are stored on an s3 bucket in AWS. 
So the 2 pages that I am referring to are present on the same s3 bucket. 
When I check the dist folder, the <head> tag is different for both pages, but when it come to Chrome, the code inside the <head> tag does not change (due to caching?). Also this is only happening on certain pages. On other pages, Chrome is not caching anything and it takes an eternity to load the next page. However, the <head> tag changes correctly for those pages.